# A stands for Accumulator then why X is used instead of R to represent register

Tags: assembly, x86, naming, cpu-registers

Hello friends please tell me .....
The general purpose registers are AX, BX, CX, DX...
A stands for Accumulator then why X is used instead of R to represent register.

Comment: Because `AX` is made off `AH` and `AL`.

Comment: @WeatherVane The linked question is slightly different and doesn't answers OPs specific question.